# is it possible to navigate with MKMapKit between the own point and an MKAnnotation?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview, mkannotation

if i wanted to implement something like a carfinder, is it posible that on the mkmapview i can get routing-information ?
maybe the line, we know from google-maps or any information in an csv (or sth like that) that tells some waypoint-information ?

Comment: What's wrong with simply setting a pinpoint in the Maps app?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post about drawing polylines as MKMapAnnotations, with sample code: http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108.

Comment: Also have a look at the link in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974056/routing-polylines-in-iphone-google-maps